# I can't find the file that I generated with my mobile application

Tags: android, firemonkey, c++builder

I've started programming Android apps with Firemonkey (RAD Studio 11).

The first task I do is save a file... I use this code:

```
UnicodeString TestPath = System::Ioutils::TPath::GetDocumentsPath();
 
Prueba = "7=5:0:6=?=<=9>5>9<7:"                  

TStreamWriter* File = new TStreamWriter(new TFileStream(TestPath+"/proof.txt", fmCreate), TEncoding::UTF8, 1024);

for(int b=1;b<Prueba.Length();b++)
{
    File->Write(Prueba.SubString(b,1));
}
File->WriteLine();

File->Flush();
File->Close();

delete File->BaseStream;
delete File;
```

When compiling, it seems that everything works perfectly, and on my mobile app the form is displayed correctly (emulating).

The problem is that I don't know where it saves the file on the device, I can't even find it in the mobile app's folder.

I can't find it in the internal storage of the mobile: */data/data/<com.myproject>/files*, or on the SD card, or via the PC.

Where should I look?

Comment: You did not tell us how you tried to find the file in /data/data/.. but if you used another app for it then indeed other apps cannot see your private files. Try another path. A public path.

Comment: Thanks for answering...
I tried to access the file, from a files explorer app on my mobile (where I saved the .txt), but I see that the planting is still wrong... I will study how to save the file so that its access is public.

Thank you.

Comment: @neg1414 "*I will study how to save the file so that its access is public*" - try `TPath::GetSharedDocumentsPath()` instead. See [Standard RTL Path Functions across the Supported Target Platforms](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Standard_RTL_Path_Functions_across_the_Supported_Target_Platforms)

Comment: @neg1414 On a side note: why are you writing `Prueba` to the file 1 char at a time? You are skipping the last char, as your loop needs to use `<=` instead. You should get rid of the loop entirely and use `File->WriteLine(Prueba);` instead. Also, you can construct the `TStreamWriter` so it creates + manages its own `TFileStream` internally, eg: `new TStreamWriter(TPath::Combine(TestPath, _D("proof.txt)"), false, TEncoding::UTF8, 1024);` In which case, you can then get rid of `delete File->BaseStream;` since `delete File;` will handle that for you. IOW, simplify your code whenever possible.